# How do I take large number of ints as inputs in array,I want an array to accept over a 1k number of ints but it seems like it is not able to do so?

Tags: arrays, testcase

Thanks for looking over to my problem, so I want a c++ array of integers to store a large number of elements like in one of my test cases I need it to store about 950 integers and array size is given previously but somehow it doesn't want to take those many number of ints as input and store them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ull;
int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  ull a[n];
  for (ull i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin>>a[i];
  }
  for (auto x : a)
  {
     cout<<x<<" ";
  }
   return 0;
}
```

I expect it to store a given number of integers like a 1000 to the max but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using malloc to dynamically allocate memory for the array. If I recall correctly, you can't statically specify it because the integer n is not known at compile time.

Comment: sure I'll try using new

Comment: ok looks like I'm done by use of new keyword thanks Arch2K ;)